# Плагин для wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-plugin

Как можно сделать плагин для wordpress из сайта на php. То есть имеется скрипт с нужным функционалом которого нету в wp, хочется внедрить его в wordpress

Comment: читаешь документацию по плагинам вордпресс. далее пишешь на основе документации

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0